# travelling before Visa Extension to home country

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, spain, visa-extensions

My friend is in Spain on a student visa who is an Indian citizen. His visa is going to expire on  27-05-2018, he wants to travel India on 23-05-2018 and go back to Spain in 10 days. He has already applied for visa extension can he travel to India and go back to Spain?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, your friend needs the "visa extension" to be approved and the appropriate document to be issued (whether a passport sticker or residence permit card) before travel.  If your friend has to leave before receiving the document, it will be necessary to get a new visa from a Spanish consulate in India before returning to Spain.

Comment: he has already applied for visa extension but the visa office told that he would get his visa on june 10 he cant wait that long as it is emergency is there any other way so that he can get his visa extension little early  i.e before he leaving spain?

Comment: @katigar nandini What’s the emergency? If that’s not too personal to post here

Comment: @katigharnandini the only other hope (as far as I'm aware) would be to ask the office that is processing the application whether there is expedited service available in light of the emergency.  Even if Spain would allow him to return, he will need some document to show the airline that Spain will allow him to return; otherwise he will not be allowed to board the plane.  He can either get that from the office in Spain or from the Spanish consulate in India.

Comment: @Traveller one of his family member is in hospital

Comment: @katigar nandini So why not go now for say a week and return in time to collect his new visa before the old one expires?